# Swift Package Manager to Cocoapods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I am developing an iOS Package with Swift Package Manager. Unfortunately, one of my client wants to use this package with Cocoapods. I found a lot of tips to move from Cocoapods to SPM but not in the other way.

Is there a way to do it ? Without recreating a new project?
Is there also a way to export the package as pre compiled package (via Cocoapods) ?

Comment: When you create a SPM, you mostly say : Use these code files, and create a package from that. Well, CocoaPods does exactly the same. So you can "mimic" the logic of your Package.swift, and create a Podpsec from it. You can check at open source lib, like Aleamofire, etc, that manage both.

Comment: And yes on the second question. See vendored_frameworks.

Comment: Ok thank you, I created the Podspec file as you suggested.
@RobNapier I found the "vendored_frameworks" option and add it to my Podspec. But I don't know how to create the pre-compiled version of my package. 
Is it just "Build" the package and then add the name of the build to the Podspecs ?

Comment: Yes, though generally the point is put the framework and podspec into another repository so you don't publish your source; it would depend on what the goal is.